# Should we use the Russian or the English language?

Tags: discussion, working-language

Do you think that the authors of Russian answers understand our English comments that we put under their answers? Has the knowledge of English became a requirement to participate in the activities of the RL&U site?

Do you think that we should leave it as it is? I have a feeling that if we'd post our "Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta" comments in both English and Russian, it would have a better effect?

On the other hand, do you believe that Russian answers are understandable for foreign users of our site?

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking about this... And my solution is: let's translate the pro-forma comments. :) I'll post them below.

---

**Notes**:

1. Don't translate the "titles" (e.g. "Answers just to say Thanks!"), since they serve as a reference for the mods.
2. $SITENAME$ is a variable, no need to translate it (leave it as is in the translation).
3. Also don't translate things as `(http://$SITEURL$/privileges)`.

---

#### Answers just to say Thanks!

`Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://$SITEURL$/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the $SITENAME$ way of saying thank you.`

#### Nothing but a URL (and isn't spam)

`Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.`

#### Requests to OP for further information

`This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.`

#### OP using an answer for further information

`Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.`

#### OP adding a new question as an answer

`If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button.`

#### Another user adding a 'Me too!'

`If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.`

#### Answer is too short / Low quality answer score

`Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.`

#### Translation Requests

`We do not forbid translation requests but note that **this is not a translation service**, so we will close any translation request that does not show research effort. You must make sure you clearly show it in your question if you want to avoid it. Note that you can edit your question and improve it by using the "edit" button below it. When you're done, flag it for moderator attention and we'll reopen it.`

Answer (score 3):

English is de facto the lingua franca of the Internet so we can expect some basic knowledge of English from visitors of a site which, to begin with, does not even have a Russian interface.

Using Russian outside the context is in my opinion quite unfriendly to the beginner learners of the language which constitute the major part of all non-former-USSR Russian speakers. During my attempts to learn Japanese I was, frankly speaking, scared by all-kanji sites. If I were to ask a question regarding Japanese, I would use a site I saw was OK to ask questions in a language I know. And as people can't really read (when it comes to rules, FAQs and manuals) we can only show it with example: by asking and answering in English and encouraging others to do the same.

As for Russian warnings, it has been noticed that trolls and other lower life forms tend to behave when told so in a foreign language. They cannot exercise their "wit" as they usually don't speak English well enough for that, but most of them are able to understand or at least Google translate the warnings.